# android, how to check or find a active notification match custom data

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

android app, one module receiving different type of data from remote, and pass the data to a 3rd party notification lib to build and post a data specific notification to the notification drawer.

However, if later it receives a new data and if that data type still has a active notification in the notification drawer (user has not tapped on it yet), the module needs to check and find the active notification for that type, and to pass the notification tag, id and data to the notification lib to update the existing active notification.

In the module that receiving the data from remote, it can get all of the active notifications

```
var foundAndReplaced = false
val activeSbn: StatusBarNotification[] = NotificationManager.getActiveNotifications()
for for (i in activeSbn.indices)  {
    val id = activeSbn[i].getId()
    val tag = activeSbn[i].getTag()
    val notification: Notification = activeSbn[i].getNotification()

    val thePendingIntent: PendingIntent = notification.contentIntent()

    ///
    // check if thePendingIntent was build with same data type, how???
    // foundAndReplaced = true
    if (foundAndReplaced) {
        theNotificationHandler.repostNotification(tag, id, data)
        break
    }
    ///

}
if (!foundAndReplaced) {
   theNotificationHandler.postNotification(data) // build and post a new notification for that data type
}
```

But how to check if the Notification is the one having the specific data type?

The thought was, for example, received data {dataType: A, latestData; B}.

Then get the Intent out of the PendingIntent, and check the Intent, something like what the below would do:

```
/// ??? not sure how to do this, it does not have the getIntent()
var oldIntent = thePendingIntent.getIntent()
foundAndReplaced =  (oldIntent.getString(DATA_TYPE_KEY == "A") // this active notification is for the dataTYpe == A
```

And when the updated notification is tapped, the intent will be passed to the Activity configured in the Intent with the new data "B".

Is there a way to check the data within the notification's pendingIntent/Intent? Or how to check a notification against some data?

**Edit:** to summarize what would like to do

1. when receiving the push notification from FCM messaging, a notification is displayed and kept in the notification drawer (until user tap on it). And an Intent (with the custome data) is put in the PendingIntent to react on user's tap (open an activity and pass the intent to it, etc.)

```
received custom data: {dataType: A, latestData; Dat-A}
and put in the Intent: 
val customData = "{dataType: A, latestData; Dat-A}"
val intent = Intent(this, PushHandlerActivity::class.java).apply {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    putExtra(CUSTOM_MESSAGE_KEY, customData)

}
val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)
...
and then build the notification and post it:
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!")
        // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        
with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build())
}
```

2. If receiving a new push which has same custom data type as a previously received push, and if the previously posted notification is still active (user has not tapped on it) in the notification drawer, there should not be a new notification to be constructed and posted to the notification drawer, but instead it should find out the previously posted notification (untapped and still active in the notification drawer), and update the custom data put in the intent given to the PendingtIntent.

Example. first time got push data: `{dataType: A, latestData; Dat-A}`

later it receives another push with data

`{dataType: A, latestData; Dat-B}`

what it needs to do now is to check the active notifications (by `NotificationManager.getActiveNotifications()`), to find if there is one who has the custom data type == "A", if it is found then update that active notification's intent's cutomData (was put in its extra) to `{dataType: A, latestData; Dat-B}`.

The problem is from the active notification (a `StatusBarNotification`) it can get the pendingIntent:

```
val thePendingIntent: PendingIntent = aStatusBarNotification.contentIntent()
```

but since the original intent was put inside the pendingIntent (via `PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)`), so needs to get the intent out from the pendingIntent first. But seems cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the `Intent` out of a `PendingIntent`.

You could use different ACTIONs in the `Intent`s for different data types, so when you get new data for a specific data type, you can update the data in any existing `PendingIntent` for that data type. Just use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to update the data in an existing `PendingIntent`.

NOTE: I'm assuming the "data" you have in the `Intent` is stored as "extras", and NOT in the URI fields.

---

Here is an example:

```
val customData = "{dataType: A, latestData; Dat-A}"
val customAction = "DataTypeA" // different string for each data type
                               //  ensures a unique PendingIntent for
                               //  each data type
val intent = Intent(this, PushHandlerActivity::class.java).apply {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    action = customAction
    putExtra(CUSTOM_MESSAGE_KEY, customData)
}
// Using FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT just updates the "extras" on an existing
//  PendingIntent
val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
      intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

This code will create a different `PendingIntent` for each different data type. But if a `PendingIntent` for a specific data type already exists, this will simply update the "extras" in the existing `PendingIntent`. You should not even have to post the `Notification` again if it already exists.

Comment: thanks @davidWasser!. I am not sure I follow you. when receiving FCM message it can loop through the active notifications, and check on each ones i.e. `val thePendingIntent: PendingIntent = notification.contentIntent()`. But how to determine this pendingIntent is a match (against the dataType in FCM msg)? And after find match how to  `update the data in any existing PendingIntent` with the new data from msg?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. I don't understand what you are trying to do. Maybe update your question with more information, including details.

Comment: I tried to explain more in the Edit section, please see if it make sense. thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you use a different notificationID for each different data type?

Comment: not likely, the module builds and posts notification I believe it generates it randomly, and the data type covers  a lot of the topics, from to news, sports, finance, politics, life style etc. etc.  Some difficulty come to a dynamic datatype, maybe a news and to be updated later with a type is not pre defined. it can only get the key from the `dataType` and then do the search.

Comment: OK, then you will need to store the relevant information in a database. Because you cannot extract the data from the `PendingIntent`

Comment: However, the code that you have isn't going to create more than 1 `PendingIntent` no matter how many times you call it. And that `PendingIntent` will always have the "extras" from the most recent time you called `PendingIntent.getActivity()`.

Comment: no, the code is copied from google doc as a snippet to show where the custom data is set in the Intent, and how the intent is set in the PendingIntent and which is set in the final built notification. The module builds the notification may use different ones, such as `PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)`. Was just borrow the coed trying to explain the problem that it needs to get the original intent out from the pendingIntent for the custom data. Seems this not support by android api.